# Automatically toggle between two divs

Tags: javascript, css, animation, jquery-animate, fade

I have two divs nested in a containing div and want to continuously switch between the two divs.

```
  <div style="position: relative; top: 50px; width: 778px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <div id="alerts" style="float: right; width:200px; height: 25px; background: goldenrod; border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px; font: 11px Arial; color: #404040; overflow: hidden;"> 
      <div id="Mass_alert" class="alert" style="position: relative; top: 0px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;"></div>
      <div id="Devotion_alert" class="alert" style="position: relative; top: 20px; margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 10px; text-align: center;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

$('#alerts').ready(function(){
    $('#Mass_alert').ready(function(){
    fadein_Mass();
    });
});

function fadein_Mass() {
    $('#Devotion_alert').fadeOut(600, function() {
    $('#Mass_alert').fadeIn(600);
    fadein_Devotion();
    });
}

function fadein_Devotion() {
    $('#Mass_alert').fadeOut(600, function() {
    $('#Devotion_alert').fadeIn(600);
    fadein_Mass();
    });
}
```

I'd like to be able to do that with a fade effect: fade `Mass_alert` out, fade `Devotion_alert` in.  What id the best way to do that?

**EDIT**
**This worked**

```
  <div style="position: relative; top: 0px; width: 778px; margin: 0 auto;"> 
    <div id="alerts" style="float: right; width:260px; height: 25px; background: goldenrod; border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px; font: 11px Arial; color: #101010;">
      <div id="Mass_alert" class="alert" style="position: relative; top: 3px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; width:100%; height: 20px;">Mass alert</div>
      <div id="Devotion_alert" class="alert" style="position: relative; top: -17px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; width:100%; height: 20px;">devotion alert</div>
    </div>
  </div>

$(document).ready(function() {  
    var continuous = function () {
    $("#Mass_alert").fadeToggle(6000, 'swing');
    $("#Devotion_alert").fadeToggle(6000, 'swing');   
    };
    $("#Devotion_alert").hide();
    setInterval(continuous,600); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var continuous = function() {
    $("#Mass_alert").fadeToggle(600);
    $("#Devotion_alert").fadeToggle(600);   
}

setInterval(continuous,600);
```

This will continuously happen every 600ms.

Comment: This almost works but only shows the `Mass_alert`.  The second div `Devotion_alert` isn't shown.

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery you can do the following:

```
$('#Mass_alert').toggle(100);
$('#Devotion_alert').toggle(100);
```

This is assuming one of the divs is initially hidden.  The argument passed to toggle is the duration of the transition effect.

Comment: While you're at it, don't waste the use of classes by putting inline styling. It's very messy and unprofessional, and adds to your page load. Better to place styles where they belong, in a style sheet. You can have multiple classes on a single element, so having <div class="alert mass"> and <div class="alert devotion"> are perfectly valid and much cleaner.

Comment: @Joe If I want a fade effect would this be achieved with the code in the edits?

Comment: If you are referring to Lazerblade's edit, then yes, it does not matter how you select the elements, as long as you call toggle() with a duration argument.

Comment: If I only put the toggle code that you suggested with `Devotion_alert` hidden initially, then `Mass_alert` flashes quickly then the containing div is blank.